# Title has "invisible border", so not whole text is seen (DaVinci Resolve)

Tags: editing, davinci-resolve, fusion

thank you for helping me! Now, at the beginning of my video (I'm working in DaVinci Resolve), I want to add a table of contents. I thought about using a title to do that. But when I paste the text and then increase the line spacing, the text seems to be cut off. It seems like there's an invisible box, so the text just isn't allowed to get over that border and therefore it gets cut off. I searched in the settings, watched several videos, but I couldn't find a answer.

Again, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the text gets created inside of “canvas” with the dimensions of the timeline.  So, if you have a 720p timeline, and scale up the text enough, it’ll get cropped when it runs out of room on the sides.  So be sure you’re scaling up the canvas, not the text.  Btw I put “canvas” in “scare quotes” because it’s not the terminology Resolve uses. A compound clip or fusion clip are two container types you might actually be using.  Also, I say “usually” because I think there may be exceptions, such as the legacy title tool, but I’m not near a machine to check.